# Extending IQueryable and parsing a property

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm fairly new to linq and wanted to delve in a bit deeper by extending IQueryable. I want to create a simple extension method that queries a date range. Something that will be the equivalent to:

```
IQuerable.Where(x => x.Date > fromDate && x.Date < toDate);
```

but with some extra processing on the dates.  I want to be able to parse a property to perform the query so the method call will be something like:

```
IQueryable.WhereDateRange(x => x.Date, fromDate, toDate);
IQueryable.WhereDateRange(x => x.AnotherDate, fromDate, toDate);
```

I've been looking into something like below but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDateRange<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, DateTime> getter, DateTime from, DateTime to) {
//query here
}
```

Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDateRange<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> getter,
    DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    Expression body = getter.Body;

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.And(
            Expression.GreaterThan(body, Expression.Constant(from)),
            Expression.LessThan(body, Expression.Constant(to))
        ),
        getter.Parameters);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

For info, though; I usually assume that a range is `>= start` and `< end`, so I'd use `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual`.

Making that more reusable (and noting that I'm using `GreaterThanOrEqual` here):

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereInRange<T, TValue>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector,
    TValue from, TValue to)
{
    Expression body = selector.Body;

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.And(
            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                body, Expression.Constant(from, typeof(TValue))),
            Expression.LessThan(
                body, Expression.Constant(to, typeof(TValue)))
        ),
        selector.Parameters);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

(need to specify the `TValue` on the constants in this case, since `null` will otherwise cause big problems)

Comment: Another note: this will only work on an outer most IQueryable, if you use this inside a sub query in linq to sql or entity framework it will fail since the providers does not know how to translate this method. you have to do some fancier tricks for this to work

Comment: @Roger anything you can do with query syntax can also be done manually, ultimately

Comment: can you really support the above methods in subqueries without replacing all other methods like select,where or wrapping the IQueryable ?

Comment: You would have to write the entire thing manually and it isn't pretty, but sure: you can do it.